# Synchronize timetables stored in a structure

Tags: matlab, synchronize, timetable

I am dynamically storing data from different data recorders in timetables, nested in a structure `DATA`, such as `DATA.Motor` (timetable with motor data), `DATA.Actuators` (timetable with actuators data) and so on.

My objective is to have a function that synchronizes and merges these timetables so I can work with one big timetable.

I am trying to use `synchronize` to merge and synchronize those timetables:

```
fields = fieldnames(DATA);    
TT = synchronize(DATA.(fields{1:end}));
```

but get the following error:

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 3 results.
```

This confuses me because `DATA.(fields{1})` return the timetable of the first field name of the `DATA` structure.

Any thought on how I can solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `fields{1:end}` is returning a "comma-separated list", and you're not allowed to use one of those as a struct dot-index expression. I.e. it's as if you tried the following, which is not legal:

```
DATA.('Motor','Actuators')
```

One way to fix this is to pull out the values from `DATA` into a `cell` array, and then you can use `{:}` indexing to generate the comma-separated list as input to `synchronize`, like this:

```
DATA = struct('Motor', timetable(datetime, rand), ...
              'Actuators', timetable(datetime, rand));
DATA_c = struct2cell(DATA);
TT = synchronize(DATA_c{:});
```